# Build fails when trying to compile spring roo sample heroku app

Tags: java, spring-mvc, heroku, spring-roo

I'm trying to test out the sample app for spring/roo/heroku here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/spring-mvc-hibernate

When I run 'mvn package' I get this output: http://pastie.org/8263189

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: There are test failures.

From the exception It seems your test data is not correct.

If you okay with skip the test please run the below command else you need to fix the test failures.

mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Comment: Easy money...thanx for the tip!